# How do I develop cpan modules without installing them?

Tags: perl, cpan, locallib

I have taken the source checkout of two cpan modules : A and B.

Both the modules A and B are developer releases.

B has a dependency on A.

My question is how do I work on B without installing A.

(I already have an older version of A installed)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to have module `A` available sometimes, such as when you're working on module `B`, but not for your regular perl fun, you can look into `local::lib`, which is a simple way to install some modules to a user-specified directory. Then when you wish to work on module `B` simply add the directory where module `A` is installed to your `PERL5LIB` environment variable, and remove it when you do not need it. See documentation for `local::lib`: [http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?local::lib](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?local%3a%3alib)

Comment: `local::lib` is an overkill. Maybe I can point PERL5LIB to the blilb/lib of A and work on B.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use [lib](http://search.cpan.org/dist/lib/) like this:

```
perl -Mlib=/some/dir/module/lib program.pl
```

Comment: `perl -I/some/dir/module/lib program.pl`

Comment: If the `A` library does not work out of the box and has a required build step (e.g. XS modules, code-modifying templates), run the build step first (i.e. `make` or `./Build`) and then use the [`blib`](http://p3rl.org/blib) pragma, thus: `perl -Mblib=/some/dir/A program.pl` - It is safe to use the `blib` pragma even if not strictly required, so I recommend to use it in any case.